# Return all values from indexedDB database objectStore

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexeddb

Simply trying to write a 'selectAll' method that takes the objectStore name as a parameter and returns ALL its containing key/value pairs, rather than simply running a callback on each iteration of the object store.

In essence, mimicking synchronous behaviour when performing an indexedDB transaction.

```
var results = []

request.onsuccess = function(e) {

    var result = e.target.result;

    if (!result) {
        //I could call successcallback here with JUST this 'row' of data
        successCallback(result);
        return;
    }

    //I could push the results into an array here, but I would need to 'wait' until all the onSuccess methods have fired before returning it.
    results.push(result.value);
    result.continue();
}
```

I'm using Angular, I think promises could be the answer. In particular, could $q.all() be helpful in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a simpler problem than I had thought. I switched the above code to the following...

```
function selectAll(model, successCallback) {
    ...
    request.onsuccess = function(e) {

        var result = e.target.result;

        if (result) {
            results.push(result.value);
            result.continue();
        } else {
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                successCallback(results);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I used a successCallback as a parameter, the calling function then returned a promise to IT'S calling function...

```
db.selectAll(model, function(results) {
    deferred.resolve(results);
})
```

Important to note the

```
$rootScope.$apply(function() {
```

around the callback call when using Angular.

Comment: An other possibility is using the oncomplete callback of the transaction object.